# Laravel: HTTPrequest to another server

Tags: php, http, laravel, httprequest

How to make http request to another server through Laravel?

I'll be pleased to provide whatever information you need

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends how complex the request needs to be. You can use curl or even, file_get_contents for simple get requests, or install a package like Guzzle for more complex things.

https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Answer (score 1):

With 'normal' PHP, you can use Curl to work with the http protocol (POST/GET). If you are using Laravel, you can either build your own curl methods or you can use a 3rd party curl library compatible with composer/Laravel:

```
https://packagist.org/packages/unikent/curl
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Guzzle 
add the dependency package in the composer.json file

```
{
    "require": {
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0" //you can change the version 
    }
}
```

make composer install or update

To create your very first request with guzzle, a code snippet as simple as below will work:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Message\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Message\Response;

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->get("https://api.github.com/");
retrun $response;
```

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you are running an old Laravel version or don't want to bother with guzzle, you can always use php-curl:

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

Then create a function for your needs eg POST:

```
function httpPost($url, $data){
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}
```

or GET

```
public function httpGet($url){
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}
```

Simply call your function in controller:

```
$response = $this->httpPost($url, $data); 
$response = $this->httpget($url);
```

Where $url is your endpoint where you need to send request and $data - parameters required.

Answer (score 0):

First of all run this command

composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->get("http://www.somewebsite.com/getSmth");
    $response = (string) $response->getBody();
    return $response;
```

getBody() function will return object.

You can use via converting to string and after that if you want you can change it to integer also

```
    $response = (int) (string) $response->getBody();
```